Azure Arc unsupported Linux distribution: Ubuntu:24.04
I have a  Microsoft Azure enviroment and a second data center with compute engine instances in Google Cloud.
I want to install Defender on my Google Cloud compute engine instances. They are running the latest Ubuntu LTS, which is 24.04 at the moment.
I created a Azure Arc script to entroll them into Microsoft Azure:
Azure Arc > Azure Arc resources > Machines > +Add > Add a machine > Add multible servers > Generate script.
I got a script that I put into my Ubuntu compute engine machines that looks like this:
onboarding.sh
# Add the service principal application ID and secret here
ServicePrincipalId="a-b-c-d-e";
ServicePrincipalClientSecret="<ENTER SECRET HERE>";


export subscriptionId="e-f-g-h-io";
export resourceGroup="rg-prod";
export tenantId="1-2-3-4-5";
export location="norwayeast";
export authType="principal";
export correlationId="6-7-8-9-0";
export cloud="AzureCloud";


# Download the installation package
output=$(wget https://aka.ms/azcmagent -O /tmp/install_linux_azcmagent.sh 2>&1);
if [ $? != 0 ]; then wget -qO- --method=PUT --body-data="{\"subscriptionId\":\"$subscriptionId\",\"resourceGroup\":\"$resourceGroup\",\"tenantId\":\"$tenantId\",\"location\":\"$location\",\"correlationId\":\"$correlationId\",\"authType\":\"$authType\",\"operation\":\"onboarding\",\"messageType\":\"DownloadScriptFailed\",\"message\":\"$output\"}" "https://gbl.his.arc.azure.com/log" &> /dev/null || true; fi;
echo "$output";

# Install the hybrid agent
bash /tmp/install_linux_azcmagent.sh;

# Run connect command
sudo azcmagent connect --service-principal-id "$ServicePrincipalId" --service-principal-secret "$ServicePrincipalClientSecret" --resource-group "$resourceGroup" --tenant-id "$tenantId" --location "$location" --subscription-id "$subscriptionId" --cloud "$cloud" --tags "Datacenter=gcp,City=Hamina,StateOrDistrict=Hamina,CountryOrRegion=Finland" --correlation-id "$correlationId";

When I run the script I get the following error:
Retrieving distro info from /etc/os-release...
/tmp/install_linux_azcmagent.sh: unsupported Linux distribution: Ubuntu:24.04. For supported OSs, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-arc/servers/prerequisites#supported-operating-systems

On the URL provided by Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-arc/servers/prerequisites#supported-operating-systems) I see that Ubuntu 24.04 is not supported. I am wondering if I am doing something wrong, are there any other method of doing this? It feels strange that Microsoft does not support the latest Ubuntu LTS version.
